# Creating a Pandas column based on values of other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a Pandas column based on values of other columns. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'col1': [23,45,21],'col2': ['we', 'ee', 'cv'],'col3': ['y1', 'y2', 'y3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['col1','col2','col3'])
df['newCol'] = [
        'N1' if c1 == 'we' else
            'N2' if c1 == 'ee' | np.isin(c2, ['y2', 'y3']) else
                'N3'
    for c1, c2 in zip(df['col2'], df['col3'])
]
```

Above code is failing with error

```
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_or' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Could you please help me to understand what went wrong in my code?

Comment: Search `np.select` or `np.where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the word `or` (and some parantheses):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
raw_data = {'col1': [23,45,21],'col2': ['we', 'ee', 'cv'],'col3': ['y1', 'y2', 'y3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['col1','col2','col3'])
df['newCol'] = [
        'N1' if c1 == 'we' else
            'N2' if (c1 == 'ee' or np.isin(c2, ['y2', 'y3'])) else
                'N3'
    for c1, c2 in zip(df['col2'], df['col3'])
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Could use `np.select(list of conditions, listof choices, alternative choice)`

```
df['new']=np.select([df['col2']=='we',(df['col2']=='ee')|(df['col3'].isin(['y2','y3']))],['N1','N2'],'N3')



    col1 col2 col3 new
0    23   we   y1  N1
1    45   ee   y2  N2
2    21   cv   y3  N2
```

Comment: This is much more efficient than OP's original code

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code

```
df['newCol'] = [
    'N1' if c1 == 'we' else
    'N2' if c1 == 'ee' or c2 in ['y2', 'y3'] else
    'N3'
    for c1, c2 in zip(df['col2'], df['col3'])
]
df
   col1 col2 col3 newCol
0    23   we   y1     N1
1    45   ee   y2     N2
2    21   cv   y3     N2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
raw_data = {'col1': [23,45,21],'col2': ['we', 'ee', 'cv'],'col3': ['y1', 'y2', 'y3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['col1','col2','col3'])
df['newCol'] = [
        'N1' if c1 == 'we' else
            'N2' if c1 == 'ee' or (np.isin(c2, ['y2', 'y3'])) else
                'N3'
    for c1, c2 in zip(df['col2'], df['col3'])
]
```

You need to separate the operation